# Spliting a numpy ndarray using slices

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Python 2.7.3 
numpy 1.8.0

Hi all,
I am using numpy for a few months and I need help with some basic stuff. The code below should work and the bit I need help with is highlighted (# <<<<<<<):

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(12345)

samples = np.array(np.arange(400).reshape(50, 8))
nSamples = samples.shape[0]
FOLDS = 15 

foldSize = nSamples / FOLDS

indices = np.arange(nSamples)
rng.shuffle(indices)

slices = [slice(i * foldSize ,
               (i + 1) * foldSize, 1) for i in xrange(FOLDS + 1)]

for i in xrange(len(slices)):
    y = samples[indices[slices[i]]]
    x = np.array([x for x in samples if x not in samples[slices[i]]]) # <<<<<<<
    #do some processing with x and y
```

Basically random slices a 2D array row-wisely, use the full array to process and test in the sliced bit, then repeat for the for another slice util everything is done (It called an cross-validation experiment).

My question is: Is there a better way to select all rows in a ndarray but a slice? Am I missing something? What is the advised way to [x for x in samples if x not in samples[indices][0:3]] ?

Thanks in advance.

ps: masked arrays does not solve my problem.
ps1: I know it's already implemented elsewhere, I just need to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean array for the rows to select as follows:

```
indices_to_ignore = [1, 2, 3]
mask = np.ones(samples.shape[:1], dtype=np.bool)
mask[indices_to_ignore] = 0
samples[mask].shape
```

Comment: Sorry, but masking does not solve the problem for me, as I stated in the PS. Is there another solution?